# Complicated Mysql query - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

This may not seem complicated to anyone else but it is for me.

I have a mysql query that uses the `IN` clause. It gathers all data from a table that matches a PHP Array. The array is called `$IdArray`. For this example purpose lets say `$IdArray` contains these variables, `['0','1','2','3']`. So here is my code that uses the query,

```
    $secondArray = array();
    function apply_quotes($item){
        return "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($item) . "'";
    }
    $idQuotes = array_map('apply_quotes', $IdArray); 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ids WHERE id IN (" . join(',', $idQuotes) . ")";
    $results = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
        if($row['id']){
                $secondArray[] = "YES";
        }
        else{
                $secondArray[] = "NO";
             }
     }//end while loop
```

As you can tell I change the `$IdArray` so it can be placed into the `mysql_query()` function. Now `$secondArray` is an array that I am trying to store responses in. What I am trying to do is if one of the numbers stored in `$IdArray` is stored in the `ids` table is places a `YES` into `$secondArray`. But if a number in the `$IdArray` is not stored in the `ids` table it will store a `NO` into `$storedArray`.

For a little example, (for what I want to happen) as I said before lets say `$IdArray` contains `['0','1','2','3']`. 
In the table `ids` numbers `1` and `3` are stored. So when the query is ran `$storedArray` will contain this `['NO','YES','NO','YES']`.

Currently my code does not do this! What it does is only stores `YES` when a number from `$IdArray` is stored in the `ids` table. So when the query is ran (Using the same variables from above) `$secondArray` will store this `['YES','YES']`.

How can I get it to store a `NO` into `$secondArray` when the number is not stored in the `ids` table?

Comment: That is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Why bother commenting??? Clearly I am asking a question. Did you not read the last sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Start by filling in your array based on the values from `$IdArray`:

```
$secondArray = array_fill_keys($IdArray, "NO");
```

Then use your query and loop to change the elements to `YES` for each row that exists in the table.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results) {
    $secondArray[$row['id']] = "YES";
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea but when I echo the results it looks like this `["0:NO","1:YES","2:NO","3:YES"]` I don't want the number or colons inside the quotes. How can I remove the numbers?

Comment: My code doesn't do that, it just sets the elements to `YES` or `NO`.